# JWT Payload Structure

Tags: java, jwt

I am trying to set my JWT token with the following structure:

```
{
  "https://daml.com/ledger-api": {
    "ledgerId": "sandbox",
    "applicationId": "foobar",
    "actAs": ["Alice"]    
  }
}
```

With my JAVA code i cant set the order of the fields, (the output JWT presents "actAS" before "applicationId")
In the field actAs, how can i get the [ ] before the "" ? Like ["Alice"] instead of "[Alice]"?

JAVA CODE:

```
void getJWT() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
   Map<String, String> claims = new HashMap<String, String>();
   claims.put("ledgerId", "sandbox");
   claims.put("applicationId", "foobar");
   claims.put("actAs", "[Alice]");
   Map<String, Object> claimsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   claimsMap.put("https://daml.com/ledger-api", claims);
   String jwtToken = Jwts.builder()
        .setClaims(claimsMap)
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "sYn2kjibddFAWtnPJ2AFlL8WXmohJMCvigQggaEypa5E=".getBytes("UTF-8"))
        .setHeaderParam("typ", Header.JWT_TYPE)
        .compact();
   System.out.println("The generated jwt token is as follows:" + jwtToken);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried setting `actAs` from the Array of `Strings` instead of `String`?

Comment: `actAs` should be either an array of `String` or `ArrayList` of `String`

Comment: Hello, i tried now with an array of Strings and it worked, thank you